# In what vector space do the arrows we know from basic geometry live? Do they form the domain of the dot product?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, vectors, euclidean-geometry

Lots of people say that they are simply elements of $\mathbb R^3$, but I think that this is not the entire story. My guess would be that it is a three dimensional real vector space and thus can be identified with $\mathbb R^3$ once we have chosen a basis.

**Q:** Is this something that gets formalized if one studies geometry? If yes, could you please give me some insight and/or a good reference? I have to talk about the cross product and the dot product and it bugs me that I can't really say what their domain is (I assume that this is strongly correlated to my question).

Answer (score 0):

You can't add arrows based at different points.  Well, you may hear people say vectors in $\mathbf R^3$ that are parallel translates of each other are "the same", but you would not agree that the gravitational force vectors on a big rock are the same if it is dropped over one of your feet or dropped some distance away from your feet.  So there is that compelling reason not to consider vectors to be the same if they are not genuinely in the same place.

The arrows based at a common point in $\mathbf R^3$ form the tangent space to $\mathbf R^3$ at that point, and the (disjoint!) union of all those tangent spaces at different points are the tangent bundle of $\mathbf R^3$.  That is a common space where all the different "vector arrows" in $\mathbf R^3$ live.